# Magic gets and sets for Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, getter-setter

I know there exists the magic gets and sets in PHP to each attribute of a class:

```
 public function __get( $key ){
   return $this->values[ $key ]; 
}

public function __set( $key, $value )
{
    $this->values[ $key ] = $value;
}
```

However, I do not know how to use it with Laravel. I noted that Laravel considers only not null fields (according to the migration) to execute the __get and __set. I want to apply a mask to some fields, so I tried:

```
public function __get($key)  {
   if($key == 'note1')
     return $this->maskFloat($this->attributes[$attr]);    
 }
```

But there is no 'note1' field because it is nullable in the migration.

Any help. please?

Comment: Just stop making crap code and add getNote1() method.

Comment: The problem is that I have about 30 attributes, so I do not want to create 30 gets and 30 sets manually.

Comment: Your class is too large then and doing too much. Please learn more about writing SOLID code. Anyway, the phpStorm for an instance can generate code for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to use the __get/__set methods or something similar, I do not want to generate each method. I do not know why, but these methods are automatically called only for not null fields.

Comment: Another reason why good developers don't use magical methods at all.

Comment: What would be a good solution for that case, @mike?

Comment: Stop taking shortcuts and write goddamn code